# How find value of subdocument with key variable?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have db like this:

```
age: { 
      30: {
          15: {
              Man: "Hello 3015",
              Girl: "Hey 15"
              },
          30: {
              Man: "Hello 3030",
              Girl: "Hey 30"
              }
          },
      40: {
          15: {
              Man: "Hello 4015",
              Girl: "Hey 4015"
              },
          30: {
              Man: "Hello 4030",
              Girl: "Hey 4030"
              }
          },
     }
```

And now i pass 3 variables:

ageSearch = 30, numberSearch = 15, gender = "Man"

How can i get the result "Hello 3015" ?

I think it's like this:

```
var search = "age" + "." + ageSearch + "." + 
numberSearch + "." + gender

db.find({}, {search}, (err, obj) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(obj);
  }
});
```

But it's doesn't work.

Do you have idea ?

Answer (score 0):

So let's debug this:

```
var search = "age" + "." + ageSearch + "." + 
numberSearch + "." + gender
```

And you're passing in:

> ageSearch = 30, numberSearch = 15, gender = "Man"

so search is:

```
"age.30.15.Man"

db.find({}, {"age.30.15.Man"}, (err, obj) => {....
```

That doesn't look like the right syntax to me. Here's [usage examples from the drivers documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/find).

I think the first input to db.find should be the search query, you have an empty object {}.

Also a query is itself an object, not a string. So you'd want something like:

```
{'age.30.15.Man': {$exists: true}}
```

Consider whether this is really the right schema for your objects, though. You can't use an index when searching for keys, so as your data grows this will become very slow.